# How to keep record of click counter not to change when refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a noob to this.
My intention is to create a LIKE button.
I wonder how can I keep the number of clicks showing on the page not to change when I refresh the page. And how can I fix that one person can only click once.

(If you find that it's difficult to explain, you can give me the name of these lessons for my self study.)

Now i am using code from [codecademy.com](https://www.codecademy.com/ja/courses/a-simple-counter/0/1), which is

**JS**

```
function modify_qty(val) {
    var qty = document.getElementById('qty').value;
    var new_qty = parseInt(qty,10) + val;
    if (new_qty < 0) {
        new_qty = 0;
    }

    document.getElementById('qty').value = new_qty;
    return new_qty;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">    
    <input id="qty" value="0" />
    <button id="up" onclick="modify_qty(1)">LIKE</button>
</div>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: _"And how can I fix that one person can only click once."_ How could this portion of requirement be achieved ?

Comment: I believe you'll need to have a database keeping track of the number and validating that it is a new user before incrementing the like total

Comment: You would need a database backend with user accounts to realistically do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `localStorage` http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp for storage purpose.

Store objects,array as a string in `localStorage` and retrieve when needed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Thank you Nava. I will try on this.